# Does AspNetCore.TestHost support Azure Active Directory?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-testhost

I am trying to use [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/testing/integration-testing#the-test-host) to test a WebAPI that I have secured with Azure Active Directory. I am able to use PostMan to obtain a bearer token from Azure AD's oauth2/token endpoint and call HTTP GET on '/api/Values'. However, when I do the same to the TestHost Server I always get a 401 unauthorized error.

I've configured my TestHost to use the Startup class that is built into my ASP.NET Core WebAPI project (it's the one that is generated by default when you use the standard template and select Azure Active Directory as your authentication provider).

```cs
Server = new TestServer(
    new WebHostBuilder()
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    );
```

I've tried two methods of attaching the bearer token.

The first approach, using the DefaultRequestHeaders of the client I generate from the TestServer:

```cs
Client = Server.CreateClient();
Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + AccessToken);
```

The second approach is attaching the header to the request itself:

```cs
var req = _sut.Server.CreateRequest("/api/Values").AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + _sut.AccessToken);
var response = await req.GetAsync();
```

However, both of these get a 401 unauthorized.

I am using the same method to obtain a token as I do in PostMan, except in code in my automated unit tests.

```cs
public static string GetAccessToken()
{
    string token = null;
    //  Constants
    var tenant = "MY_TENANT_HERE.onmicrosoft.com";
    var serviceUri = "https://MY_TENTANT_HERE.com/WebApplicationAAD";
    var clientID = "a1d51587-bf4c-4915-b588-8df1d9fd7ac9"; // this is the Application ID for the Native App in Azure AD
    var userName = "integration_test@MY_TENANT_HERE.com";
    var password = "THE_PASSWORD_FOR_THE_TEST_ACCOUNT";
    var appClientId = "d476fd33-4cfc-4aeb-9d4d-ea4978af5660"; // this is the Application ID for the Web API app in Azure AD

    using (var webClient = new WebClient())
    {
        var requestParameters = new NameValueCollection();

        requestParameters.Add("grant_type", "password");
        requestParameters.Add("client_id", clientID);
        requestParameters.Add("username", userName);
        requestParameters.Add("password", password);
        requestParameters.Add("resource", appClientId);
        //requestParameters.Add("scope", "openid");

        var url = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenant + "/oauth2/token";
        var responsebytes = webClient.UploadValues(url, "POST", requestParameters);
        var responsebody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responsebytes);
        var jsonresult = JObject.Parse(responsebody);
        token = (string)jsonresult["access_token"];
    }

    return token;
}
```

This code produces a token. It is producing the same postman post that I am doing.

[image: get token using postman]

Doing HTTP GET on the IIS Express hosted WebAPI using the same technique WORKS.

[image: WebAPI calls with bearer token attached working too]

I suspect either AspNetCore.TestHost does not support this or I am not doing something to properly configure it to light up the Azure Active Directory config that is working when I debug on IIS Express but documentation is extremely light.